# Android Intent.ACTION_PICK

Tags: android

This code successfully retrieves images from the (emulator) SDcard:

```
    public void pickImage(View v) {     
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_GET);
    }
}
```

This returns a bunch of thumbnails titled Choose Picture. Is there any way I can intercept this and filter out certain images first? 
Clicking any thumbnail image then runs the OnActivityResult which I can intercept, but then it is too late.
I am using Metadator-extractor and only need to display images containing certain tags, but do not know how to access each
thumbnail before it arrives on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can intercept this and filter out certain images first?

Not with `ACTION_PICK`. You are welcome to query `MediaStore` for available pictures and implement your own pick activity, in which you can filter out whatever you want.